# symfony 2, for download file request return empty response with flash message set

Tags: forms, symfony, flash-message

I have a link on a web form, which points to a file download action.

```
public function downloadDataAction($data_id)
{
    //get data from database and create a zip file ($fzip) with the data

    $content = file_get_contents($fzip);
    $filename = 'mydata_' . $data_id . '.zip'; 
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/zip',
        'Content-Disposition' => "attachment; filename=" . urlencode($filename),
    ); 

    return new Response($content, 200, $headers);
}
```

The above action works as expected; zip file is downloaded, when there's a data with the specified id, and the original web form stays as it was, without any change or refresh. I don't know what response to return, when there is no data found in the database. Ideally, I'd like to set a flash message, but without a refresh, flash won't be seen on the form, and refresh will destroy entries made by a user, if there were any entries made by a user, before link was clicked. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Following code will generate refresh with setting flash message

```
if (!isset($fzip)) {
     $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice','Notice message content');

     return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_route_name'));
}
```

But you can also render some twig that will display message

```
if (!isset($fzip)) {
    return $this->render('@AcmeDemo/Default/index.html.twig', array('msg' => 'message content'));
}
```